# Delaying React Redux Action Dispatching From Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

As shown in the below code, I'm calling dispatch action function in onChange event. So everyTime when I press any key, It will dispatch the redux action. I think it is not a good approach. because If I write 'aaaa', Then action would be dispatch 4 times & update the state through reducer.

**I don't want to use onBlur event because sometime it doesn't work. What would be best approach to optimizing the code ?**

**component**

```
class abc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onFieldChange(fieldName, e) {
    e.persist();
    this.props.updateFields(`fields.${fieldName}`, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const {fields} = this.props.facilityFormStates;

    return (
      <div>        
        <div className='col-md-12'>          
          <TextField
            defaultValue={fields && fields.fullLegalName}
            onChange={(e) => this.onFieldChange('fullLegalName', e)}
            floatingLabelText="Full Legal Name *"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            fullWidth={true}
          />

          <TextField
            hintText=""
            defaultValue={fields && fields.businessName}
            onChange={(e) => this.onFieldChange('businessName', e)}
            floatingLabelText="Business or Assumed Name, if any"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            fullWidth={true}
          />

          <TextField
            hintText=""
            defaultValue={fields && fields.employerNumber}
            onChange={(e) => this.onFieldChange('employerNumber', e)}
            floatingLabelText="Federal Employer Identification Number"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            fullWidth={true}
          />

          <TextField
            hintText=""
            defaultValue={fields && fields.address}
            onChange={(e) => this.onFieldChange('address', e)}
            floatingLabelText="Street Address"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            fullWidth={true}
          />
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ 
  facilityFormStates: state.facilityFormStates, 
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateFields: (path, data) => dispatch(updateFieldsFormField(path, data))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(abc);
```

**Action**

```
import {UPDATE_FORM_ACTION} from './action-types.js'

export const updateFormField = (ObjKeyPath, value) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE__FORM_ACTION,
    ObjKeyPath,
    value,  
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import {UPDATE_FORM_ACTION} from '../../actions/action-types.js';

import _ from 'lodash';

export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_FORM_ACTION:
      return _.set(state, action.ObjKeyPath, action.value)
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: make use of debounce and call the action dispatch after a certain debounce interval, so if the use is continously tying you don't dispatch the action, but do it when there is a slight pause

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Can you please write the debounce syntax here? I'm using lodash library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `debounce` and call the action dispatch after a certain debounce interval, so if the user is continuously tying you don't dispatch the action, but do it when there is a slight pause.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFieldChange = _.debounce(
       this.onFieldChange,
            150
    );
  }

  onFieldChange = (fieldName, e) => {
    e.persist();
    this.props.updateFields(`fields.${fieldName}`, e.target.value);
  }
```